# Loop to check file existence without DIR function

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make a loop that will save the edited files in a folder in numerical order, but if I run the macro again it needs to keep from the last number:

```
wb.SaveAs "C:\User\Desktop\Data\" & i & ".dat"
i = i + 1
```

Here the code saves the files in order (1,2,3). And if I run the macro again it needs to save (4,5,6).

I tried to use this loop above to save the function:

```
Do While Dir("C:\User\Desktop\Data\" & i & ".dat") = i
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

But apparently, I can't use the `DIR` function, because I'm already using it at the end of the loop to get the next file, and the loop breaks.

```
'Get next file name
 MyFile = Dir
```

So, is there's any way to do this? I'm trying to make a function that would check and return `true` or `false` to whether a file with that number already exists, but could not make it work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use a `filesystemobject` to check if the file exists: it has a `FileExists()` method.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: hum, thanks for the tip, i don't know how to use it but i'll keep trying.

Comment: See below @Mike and let me know if it does what you're looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the largest number in the directory, and keep going from there?

This code presumes that all the files are named as such: `[numericalfilename].[extension]`   for example `"143.dat"`. This code will not work if there are alpha characters in the file-name (apart from extension)

Once you have defined `Path` and `Extension` variables, you can call the Function `NextNumber` which will give you `[MaxNumber_In_Directory] + 1`

From here you can perform your "save loop", by setting `i = NextNumber(Path, "*." & Ext)`

```
Sub test()
Dim Path As String
Dim Ext As String
Dim i as Long

' ***** REPLACE VARIABLES ******

    Path = "C:\New\New Folder"
    Ext = "dat"

' ******************************

    i = NextNumber("C:\New\New Folder", "*." & Ext)

' ********************************
' **** PERFORM SAVE CODE HERE ****
' ********************************

   'I am not 100% sure of your save loop, you'll need to modify this

    wb.SaveAs "C:\User\Desktop\Data\" & i & ".dat"
    i = i + 1


End Sub




Public Function NextNumber(strPath As String, strExt As String) As Long
Dim vArray(500)
Dim i As Long
Dim length As Long
ChDir strPath
strExtension = Dir(strExt)

        'Perform Loop
        Do While strExtension <> ""
            length = Len(strExtension) - (Len(strExt) - 2) - 1
            vArray(i) = CLng(Mid(strExtension, 1, length))
             i = i + 1
            strExtension = Dir
        Loop

NextNumber = WorksheetFunction.Max(vArray) + 1

End Function
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, i managed to make it work based on your code.